# PHP QRCODE generator with logo

Tags: php, qr-code

is there anyone knows some plugin for php to generate QRcode with logo?
like this.

[image]

please help.

Comment: I know a plugin that takes in text and encodes it in QR. Will that work for you?

Comment: @TalhaMasood : i want to generate QRcode with logo centered on it. do you have it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try http://www.unitaglive.com/qrcode or if you really need a script, this:) https://gist.github.com/NTICompass/1283249 peace. It allows many content types and heavy customization, including changing the color of the eyes; using an image as the background; many styles; shadow; redundancy; and more, also allows you to use a logo and is based off a freemium business model. The free plan has no signup

Comment: https://theqrcode.org/ is Ok

Comment: https://github.com/Intosoft/custoqr